# What Process.kill signals are available on Windows?

Tags: ruby

From the documentation for [`Process.kill`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Process.html#method-c-kill):

> Sends the given signal to the specified process id(s) if pid is
>   positive. If pid is zero signal is sent to all processes whose group
>   ID is equal to the group ID of the process. signal may be an integer
>   signal number or a POSIX signal name (either with or without a SIG
>   prefix). If signal is negative (or starts with a minus sign), kills
>   process groups instead of processes. **Not all signals are available
>   on all platforms.**

Okay, that's pretty vague. Which signals are available on what platforms? Are there any signals available on Windows?

(I tried `Process.kill(9, pid)` on Windows before and it didn't throw an error. It didn't kill the process either though... But `Process.kill("TERM", pid)` did throw an error. Go figure.)

Comment: NB that it basically "fakes" signals in windows by "performing equivalent behavior" to the linux equivalent...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think I found a solution. To find out what signals your current platform supports, run this:

```
ruby -e "puts Signal.list"
```

On Windows:

```
{"EXIT"=>0, "INT"=>2, "ILL"=>4, "ABRT"=>22, "FPE"=>8, "KILL"=>9, "SEGV"=>11, "TERM"=>15}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this article

http://blog.robseaman.com/2008/12/12/sending-ctrl-c-to-a-subprocess-with-ruby

There is good mention of `process.kill` and its turn-around mechanism

Comment: Great article. It's a bit old, but there's lots of good stuff in there.

Comment: article is pretty old, now `Process.spawn` has the `:new_pgroup` option for windows. I wonder if `kill(-pgroup)` does work now on windows. But I don't have a windows environment handy and I'm very unwilling to find a windows machine and install stuff on it to test.